# After upgrading to angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

After upgrading to angular 8, started to get these errors. Havent found anything online talking about this issue. Is it because a file cant have more than 1 export. Uploaded a sample of model file which has all th exports.

```
 "export 'IOverlays' was not found in 
  '../../../../../shared/brief-data/brief-data.models'
  ERROR in 



./client/app/viz/globe/state/submodules/display/display.actions.ts 
 41:12-34
 "export 'IPerformSettingB
ERROR in 
./client/app/viz/globe/state/submodules/display/display.actions.ts 
77:12-34
"export 'IPerformSettingBoolean' was not found in 
  '../../../models/globe'
ERROR in 
./client/app/viz/globe/state/submodules/display/display.actions.ts 
 113:12-34



export interface IGlobeTimelinePoint {
  date: Date;
}
export interface IGlobeTimelineData {
 data: IGlobeTimelinePoint[];
 presentSources: string[];
}
export interface ILiveFeedStatus {
  acm: IAcm;
  isLoading: boolean;
  hasErrors: boolean;
  error?: string;
}

export interface ILiveFeedStatuses {
   [key: string]: ILiveFeedStatus;
}

export interface ILiveFeedIcons {
  [key: string]: ILiveFeedIconConfig;
}
export interface IOntologyConfig {
    [name: string]: {
    values: string[];
};
}
```

Comment: Well, maybe check if `brief-data.models.ts` has an named export `IOverlays`?

Comment: It does, had no errors before upgrading to angular 8 @scipper

Comment: Can you please upload full source code of brief-data.models.ts and how you import it in another file

Comment: @TonyNgo added a sample of my code

Comment: These issues were never happening in angular 7

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Removing `.d` from the filename fixed it for me (e.g. `my-declarations.d.ts` -> `my-declarations.ts`.

I have no idea why though.